# Is there a way to embed openstreetmap in UIVIEW?

Tags: ios, openstreetmap

Is it possible? I need to display it for specific coordinates and draw on it: polygons and points.

This is possible on the website:

https://tereneo.azurewebsites.net/openstreetmap.html

I would like to achieve the same for ios;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do exactly.
If you want to display a website in an iOS app, you can use a WKWebView. You will have the same controls as in a web browser.

An example of a WKWebView added programmatically :

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {
    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myURL = URL(string: "https://tereneo.azurewebsites.net/openstreetmap.html")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }
}
```